# assigning variable in c# fails

Tags: c#, string, variables

I am assigning variable to another variable but it throws error

```
string conf = "[32882914,32877390,32877377,32882917,32882922,32882926,32877379,32882887,32882891,32877382,32882897,32882902,32882907,32882909]"

int sku = 34444
string param1 = "{\"SameDayDeliveryStoreNumber\":0,\"styleSkus\":[{\"StyleId\":{0},\"SkuIds\":{1}}],\"RefreshSameDayDeliveryStore\":true}",sku,conf;
```

Error:

```
unexpected value string 
varibale is already defined sku,conf
```

how to use variables in another variable in c#

Comment: You're missing the `string.Format` call: `string param1 = string.Format("{\"SameDayDeli...\":true}",sku,conf);`.  Otherwise it thinks you're trying to declare `sku` and `conf` _again_.

Comment: I suggest you use a library for generating JSON.

Comment: @Lee me too - _after_ you learn to format strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a key part of the syntax, you need `string.Format`. Your code should instead read

```
string param1 = String.Format("{{\"SameDayDeliveryStoreNumber\":0,\"styleSkus\":[{{\"StyleId\":{0},\"SkuIds\":{1}}}],\"RefreshSameDayDeliveryStore\":true}}",sku,conf);
```

There are other ways to do this that you can use, for example you can use `+`

```
string param1 = "{\"SameDayDeliveryStoreNumber\":0,\"styleSkus\":[{\"StyleId\":" + sku + ",\"SkuIds\":" + conf + "}],\"RefreshSameDayDeliveryStore\":true}";
```

Or you could use the more similar interpolation

```
string param1 = $"{{\"SameDayDeliveryStoreNumber\":0,\"styleSkus\":[{{\"StyleId\":{sku},\"SkuIds\":{conf}}}],\"RefreshSameDayDeliveryStore\":true}}";
```

Notice in the first and third examples there are three curled brackets at the end of the second parameter instead of two, this is because two would escape to a literal "}" character, to instead get the syntax `}` followed by the literal "}", three must be used

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what Alfie said, the back slashes (\) should also be escaped in C# with double back slashes.

```
"{{\\"SameDayDeliveryStoreNumber\\"
```

Comment: Those slashes should not be escaped, they are escaping the speech marks that follow them

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I stand corrected. Thank you.